# How to manage authentication and authorization in .net core based on the token received from third party rest API?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, role-base-authorization

I am developing web Application in .Net Core 3. I need to manage authentication and authorization in web app based on the JWT token received from other rest API application. Is it possible to manage role based based page and navigation between them without using/creating the database for web app? How to manage token expiration for web application if we are able to manage that?

Comment: yes you can resolve the claims from the token. Read about IdentityServer4 .

Comment: If I go with one of the sample after finding appropriate from the link  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/release/3.1/src/Security/samples/ then will it work or will be useful to me?

Comment: pluralsight is free for April, so you can try watching this course https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/authentication-authorization-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add same token validation parameters as you have in your other rest API app with same IssuerSigningKey, and use tokens with your main app as well